# php regular expression not returning matches

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have a really simple regular expression setup.

```
preg_match('/[0-9]*/', $item, $id);
```

$item's string value is "`<li class="page_item page-item-29 current_page_item"><a href="http://dcdc.siretesting.com/programs/child-care/" title="Child Care">Child Care</a></li>`"

when I `print_r($id)` I get an empty array  *Array ( [0] => )*

I tested using http://regexpal.com/ and it selects like I would expect. It highlights the number 29

I can't figure out why in PHP it's not matching properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably misguided by your pattern:

```
/[0-9]*/
```

The `*` signals that you want to match zero or more characters. `preg_match` does this, it finds zero of the character class `[0-9]` successfully and returns you the empty string.

You might meant this:

```
/[0-9]+/
```

The `+` signals that you want to match one or more instead.

Regexpal will give you all matches not only the first one. See with `preg_match_all`: [Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/KnRJkU).

Comment: thanks for the explanation. I was assuming the * ment to select 0-9 multiple times. Any reason why was it passing on the js tester but in php?

Comment: You're welcome, you can find a good introduction to regular expressions here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/ - look for the quantifier section.

Answer (score 1):

Use this with caution...

```
if (preg_match('/\d+/', $subject, $regs)) {
    $result = $regs[0];
}
```

Edit :

Use with caution because \d+ will match only the first sequence of number anywhere inside the subject string. So yeah that's not very safe to use.

Comment: Why with caution? The OP may need to know why. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `+` instead of `*`, since `*` will match zero instances. You need 1 or more via `+`.

```
preg_match('/[0-9]+/', $item, $id);

print_r($id);
Array
(
    [0] => 29
)
```

Comment: Nope, the 0 group is the full pattern, and you don't need to group it explicitly. Your pattern would introduce the group 1 which would be the same as 0 (having the same sub-pattern).

Comment: @hakre Correct. The actual problem is * instead of +

Comment: @JakeChamberlain `*` in regular expressions means "zero or more of the preceding".  `+` means "one or more of the preceding". So using `*` causes it to match everything, even if there are no digits found.